# Oracle Webcenter Content Fast Checkin not working with Siebel iFrame

Tags: oracle, iframe, siebel

I have enabled fast checkin on WCC through adding `useFastCheckin=1` as an addition configuration variable.

However, now when users upload documents to WCC through the Siebel Iframe, the documets are not displaying on the Iframe after being uploaded.
The document is available in WCC if you search for it but no documents are visible in the iFrame.

Then when removing the `useFastCheckin=1` on WCC, the documents display on siebel iFrame as normal.

Does anyone have a solution for this to allow for WCC to use fast checkin and show the documents on the iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the issue that I was facing in my above question.
I added the following two additional configuration variables to WebCenter Content General configuration:

UseSearchCache=false
SearchCacheMaxItemAgeInMinutes=0

and voila problem solved.